# Populate type Dynamic to combobox

Tags: c#, dynamic, combobox

I have some data in DB and select it into a `dynamic` variable..

```
dynamic _data;
_data = db.Select("select * from foobar");
```

This ends up with something like (**dynamic view**):

```
0 => customername => "blabla",
     companyname => "haha"
1 => customername => "hihi",
     companyname => "hoho"
```

and so on.

Debugging this dynamic type also shows me that the data exists as (**result view**)

```
0 => key => "customername", value => "blabla",
     key => "companyname", value => "haha"
1 => key => "customername", value => "hihi",
     key => "companyname", value => "hoho"
```

What I want to achive is to add this content to a combobox like

```
cmbGroup.DisplayMember = "customername";
cmbGroup.ValueMember   = "customername";
cmbGroup.DataSource    = _data;
```

or

```
cmbGroup.DisplayMember = "key";
cmbGroup.ValueMember   = "value";
cmbGroup.DataSource    = _data;
```

But both cases dont work... it allways shows me `System.Dynamc.ExpandoObject` as comboboxitems.

I tried to convert the data into a list

```
private List<string> dyn2List()
{
    List<string> ls = new List<string> { };
    foreach(var d in _data)
    {
        ls.Add(d.customername);
    }
    return ls;
}
```

and add it, what actually works somehow but this doesnt seems to be the nice way when you know what I mean. Also, if I use the list convert.... I have to avoid duplicates an this brings up a lot of other errors... (said short: dont know how)

So my question: **Is there anyway to use `<dynamic>` as Datasource in a combobox ?**

All values returned are string atm. So its still "simple".

Google didnt came up with the right results. Or may it came up with the right ones but I could not match them as needed.

This is how my dynamic data looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try projecting your data into the form you want:

```
var _data = db.Select("select * from foobar")
    .Select(d => new 
        { customername = d.customername, 
          companyname = d.comapanyname
        });

comboBox1.DisplayMember = "customername";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "companyname";

comboBox1.DataSource = _data;
```

Comment: but i dont know how many results I have... so the `new{ }` is called several times... how to loot through my dynamic data?

Comment: Since I don't have your data, I made my own demo data. Replace my `data` with your `_data`. Does it work?

Comment: still results with multiply `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`

Comment: I guess you will have to transform it, like run a linq projection over it, to make it usable. But, why are you going to all this trouble to use dynamic when you can just project the query results into a collection similar to my demo data?

Comment: i added a image of consoleoutput where you can see my dynamic data construct

Comment: If you have a better idea, you can tell me if you like to :D i select data from  mysql into an object and want to fill some fields on my gui, depending on given data. I also fill a treeview where I can select some entrys... ATM im stuck in filling the combobox with group names (each entry has one and i dont want duplicates)

Comment: What is the return type of `db.Select`?

Comment: At the moment its `List<dynamic>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145380/discussion-between-dwza-and-crowcoder).